# at what percent of physical memory usage should a person worry

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have a question that I feel could use some input from others.

My machine is 2 years old and is still running strong but I, like some users, worry at which point of physical memory use should one start to wonder if every thing is ok.

Currently when my computer sits at idle it uses about ~12-13% percent of physical memory and at peak use with some tabs open and a video playing it can go up to ~17-18% use. During gaming it may use half of what i have but that's not unheard of.

So I guess im asking is at what level of percentage use should a person start to worry when a computer is at idle?

btw here are my specs:

os - windows 7 home premium

processor - i7 4790k

phys memory - 16gb (2x8gb) corsair vengeance

video card - nvidia 960 (2gb)

mobo - asus z97- delux

ps - corsair builder cx 600 watt

Comment: Find something else (that's actually important) to worry about.

Comment: Worry about what? Damage to the memory? Needing more memory? Overuse of the system? What is your actual problem? Are you getting errors or experiencing unexpected issues and think they may be related to memory?

Comment: I'd recommend you install more memory if you had 2GB, but you have 16GB. Unless you're doing high-end professional graphics or video editing or building a virtual lab, you're not going to get anywhere close to using even more than half of what you have installed. And like sawdust said: you shouldn't be worrying about your memory.

Comment: ok to clarify on this iv noticed memory creep as I use programs then move on. After using certain programs and then ending them some of my physical memory isnt released for use in other programs (especially after using chrome). Everyone in my field that I ask this question too gives a completely different answer even myself with my three years IT experience and A+ Certification.

Answer (score 2):

Unused memory is wasted memory.

If you don't experience performance problems, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on other remarks, Linux at least tries to use all the available memory by stuffing buffers and cache into memory that is not being used by running programs.

I believe that M$ Windows is following the same philosophy in memory management.

When you should worry is when you see swapping happening which GREATLY slows down processing.

Comment: To compare to linux, for some reason(s), Windows has different strategy, it always use swap even there is plenty of free memory

Comment: From what I understand about Windows 7 and how it uses memory it does cache data for most commonly used programs to ensure that the program launches faster and is ready when needed. Other than that I'v heard too many other examples as to what 7 does with its memory.